# how to get content within a span tag

Tags: html, css, selenium, web-scraping, tags

```
#Example 1
<span class="levelone">
    <span class="leveltwo" dir="auto">
        ::before
        "Blue"
        ::after
    </span>
</span>



#Example 2
<div class="itemlist">
    <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">
        "mobile"
    </div>
</div>



#Example 3
<div class="quantity">
    <div class="color">...</div>
    <span class="num">10</span>
</div>
```

Hi, I am trying to use selenium to extract content from html. I managed to extract the content for example 1 & 2, the code that I have used is

```
example1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='leveltwo']")
example2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='itemlist']")
```

and printed out as text with

```
data = [dt.text for dt in example1] 
print(data)
```

I got "Blue" for example 1 & "mobile" for example 2. For simplicity purposes, the html given above is for one iteration, I have scraped all elements with the class mentioned above

However, for the 3rd example, I tried to use

```
example3a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='quantity']")
```

and

```
example3b = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='num']")
```

and

```
example3c = driver. find_element_by_class_name("num")
```

but all of it returned an empty list. I'm not sure is it because there is no `dir` in example 3? What method should I use to extract the "10"?

Answer (score 1):

for 3rd example, you can try the below css :

```
div.quantity span.num
```

in code you can write like this :

```
example3a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.quantity span.num")
print(example3a.text)
```

or

```
print(example3a.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract specifically the `10` you can use

```
example3a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.quantity span.num")
```

To extract both elements inside `<div class="quantity">` you can use

```
example3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='quantity']//*")
for el in example3:
    print(el.text)
```